# Proof by induction, 1 · 1! + 2 · 2! + ... + n · n! = (n + 1)! − 1

Tags: induction

So I'm supposed to prove that $$1 · 1! + 2 · 2! + \dots + n · n! = (n + 1)! − 1$$ using induction. 
What I've done

**Basic Step:**

Let $n=1$, $$1\cdot1! = 1\cdot1 = 1 = (n+1)!-1 = 2!-1 = 2-1  = 1$$

**Induction Step:**

Assume $f(k) = 1\cdot1! + 2\cdot2! + \dots + k\cdot k! = (k+1)!-1$

\begin{align}
F(k+1) &= 1\cdot1! + 2\cdot2! + \dots + k\cdot k! + (k+1)\cdot(k+1)!\\
&= (k+1)!\ - 1 + (k+1)\cdot(k+1)!\\
&= (k+1)!\cdot((k+1) - 1) = (k+1)!\cdot(k)
\end{align}

I think I'm supposed to make $(k+1)!\cdot k = ((k+1)+1)!+1 = (k+2)!-1$ but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: You made a simple mistake here: $(k+1)! – 1 + (k+1)(k+1)!$ is not $(k+1)!((k+1)-1)$, but $(k+1)!(1+(k+1)) - 1$. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Well, that was a stupid mistake... Thanks a lot!

Comment: For another proof you can use a telescopic sum, $k\cdot k!=(k+1)!-k!$

Answer (score 7):

Bernard's answer highlights the key algebraic step, but I thought I might mention something that I have found useful when dealing with induction problems: whenever you have an induction problem like this that involves a sum, rewrite the sum using $\Sigma$-notation. It makes everything more concise and easier to manipulate:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i\cdot i!&=\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot i!+(k+1)(k+1)!\tag{by definition}\\[1em]
&= [(k+1)!-1]+(k+1)(k+1)!\tag{induction hyp.}\\[1em]
&= (k+1)![1+(k+1)]-1\tag{rearrange}\\[1em]
&= (k+1)![k+2]-1\tag{simplify}\\[1em]
&= (k+2)!-1.\tag{by definition}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to prove that
$$(k+1)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)!=(k+2)!\,\color{red}{\mathbf -}\,1$$
Simplifying the $- 1$ terms and dividing both sides by $(k+1)!$ yields
Simplifying both sides by $(k+1)!$ yields
$$1+(k+1)=k+2,$$
which is pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: This doesn't look like it matches the original question.

Comment: @PeterSchorn: as far as I remember, I only tried to explain why the inductive step was easy.